# Equal Heights on Divs Containing Other Divs

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am currently setting up a webpage with a layout like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="content">
    ...content...
  </div>

  <div id="sidebar">

    <div id="subnav">
      ...subnav...
    </div>

    <div id="contactform">
      ...contact form...
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

The wrapper div is a darker background, while the content div and the subnav/contactform div's have a white background (The sidebar div itself is transparent).

I've tried all the possible equal heights jquery and CSS tricks out there, but none of them seem to work for a div containing other divs of varying heights inside of it.

Is there a fix to my issue?

Comment: Post your sample page up on jsbin.com or jsfiddle.com so we can look at it

Comment: The content and sidebar don't need to be the same height. When content ends, so should the box that contains it. That's how we know there's no more content to follow.

Comment: In most cases, the sidebar div with the subnav and contact form stretch much further down the page than the content div. I would like to see if there's a way to stretch the content div's height down to the bottom of the entire sidebar div.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want Faux Columns:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/

Comment: I would use this, but there's about 20px of open space between the subnav and contact form div's in the sidebar, so using a solid background image would be ruled out.